# Cannot add Image to SVG Circle in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm working with d3, but can't seem to add an image to my SVG circle? I've tried different ways but won't give the output I want. Can someone help me?

The image loaded correctly so that shouldn't be the problem. I also tried the fill attribute but it didn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/style.css";
import $ from "jquery";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import btcImage from "../images/btc.png";

const crypto = require("../data/cryptoData.json");
const coins = [];

for (let i = 0; i < crypto.data.length; i++) {
  var coin = crypto.data[i];
  coins.push(coin);
}

var data = [];

coins.forEach((coin) => {
  var text = coin.symbol;
  var r = coin.quote.USD.market_cap / 4000000000;
  data.push({
    text: text,
    category: coin.quote.USD.percent_change_24h,
    image: btcImage,
    r: r,
    r_change_1: coin.quote.USD.market_cap / 4000000000,
    r_change_2: coin.quote.USD.market_cap / 4000000000,
  });
});

function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
  return function (d) {
    var r = d.r + 10,
      nx1 = d.x - r,
      nx2 = d.x + r,
      ny1 = d.y - r,
      ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && quad.point !== d) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
          y = d.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = d.r + quad.point.r;
        if (l < r) {
          l = ((l - r) / l) * (1 + alpha);
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
const bubbleCloud = (element) => {
  var container = d3.select(".bubble-cloud");
  var $container = $(".bubble-cloud");
  var containerWidth = $container.width();
  var containerHeight = $container.height();
  var svgContainer = container
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", containerWidth)
    .attr("height", containerHeight);

  // prepare layout
  var force = d3.layout
    .force()
    .size([containerWidth, containerHeight])
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .friction(1);
  // load data
  force.nodes(data).start();

  // create item groups
  var node = svgContainer
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

  // create circles

  node
    .append("defs")
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("height", 60)
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
      return d.image;
    })
    .attr("height", 60)
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

  node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return d.image;
    });

  // create labels
  node
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.text;
    })
    .classed("text", true)
    .style({
      fill: "#ffffff",
      "text-anchor": "middle",
      "font-size": "12px",
      "font-weight": "bold",
      "text-transform": "uppercase",
      "font-family": "Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif",
    });

  node
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.category;
    })
    .classed("category", true)
    .style({
      color: "white",
      "font-family": "Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif",
      "text-anchor": "middle",
      "font-size": "9px",
    });

  node
    //.append("line")
    //.classed("line", true)
    //.attr({
    //  x1: 0,
    //  y1: 0,
    //  x2: 0,
    //  y2: 0,
    //})
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", function (d) {
      return d.stroke;
    });

  // put circle into movement
  force.on("tick", function (e) {
    d3.selectAll("circle")
      .each(collide(0.1))
      .attr("r", function (d) {
        return d.r;
      })
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        // boundaries
        if (d.x <= d.r) {
          d.x = d.r + 1;
        }
        if (d.x >= containerWidth - d.r) {
          d.x = containerWidth - d.r - 1;
        }
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        // boundaries
        if (d.y <= d.r) {
          d.y = d.r + 1;
        }
        if (d.y >= containerHeight - d.r) {
          d.y = containerHeight - d.r - 1;
        }
        return d.y;
      });

    d3.selectAll("line").attr({
      x1: function (d) {
        return d.x - d.r + 10;
      },
      y1: function (d) {
        return d.y;
      },
      x2: function (d) {
        return d.x + d.r - 10;
      },
      y2: function (d) {
        return d.y;
      },
    });

    d3.selectAll(".text")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y - 10;
      });

    d3.selectAll(".category")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y + 20;
      });
    force.alpha(0.1);
  });
};

class Bubbles extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="bubble-cloud" ref={bubbleCloud}></div>;
  }
}
export default Bubbles;
```

I think I'm overlooking something

Output:
[image]

Comment: You have to add a unique id to your pattern, and then you should be filling your circle by referencing the pattern id, not the image URL. The normal SVG would be fill="url(#yourpatternid)"  You might want to look here for a proper d3 example: https://observablehq.com/@dersteppenwolf/test-images

Comment: @MichaelMullany Thankyou! I got it done! now i have the problem that the image is not centered in the circle...

Comment: Try adding .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid slice"); to your image